# How Deploy Our WebApp into Liferay

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide

I am new to Liferay, I have a webapp (built with Struts/Spring/Hibernate).

My question is how to deploy this WebApp into Liferay 6.2 Environment. Is this possible?

Comment: It is not clear what are your exact intentions... I guess that you want to integrate your application with Liferay (not just deploy alongside it). You should check https://www.liferay.com/documents/14/8440801/Liferay+Application+Integration+Strategies.pdf

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run it as a liferay portlet - first of all you have to convert your web application into a portlet application. Which means at least creating a few additional configuration files (liferay-display.xml, liferay-portlet.xml, etc). Not difficult but best to read some docs first.

If you want to simply run it along with your liferay, just put your WAR to /liferay/tomcat/webapps folder and it will get deployed. It won't be a portlet but will still run as a web-app.

Answer (score 1):

We can deploy the web applications into liferay environment but I am not sure if it work properly or not..
Because portlet work flow is different from web application flow.
We need framework specific bridges that will convert normal web application flow into portlet work flow.

Like Spring Portlet MVC

Liferay Faces for JSF

Struts Bridges

For more liferay stuff please have look into http://liferaysavvy.com

Please have look into following links

https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Web+Applications+Integration/pop_up?_36_version=1.2

https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/9093005
https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/developing-applications-for-liferay

Comment: I don't want to sound offensive, but you should work on your English. The answer is barely readable (if at all).