# How to deploy a micro service (.war) into liferay tomcat server?

Tags: java, tomcat, liferay

I have a legacy application running in liferay (V 5.2) - tomcat server (V 6.0.16) and Now, I had to add a small functionality to the existing application. For doing so I have written a micro service and have the .war file of the micro service ready which I tested in a different tomcat (V 7.0.59) and it's working fine.

Now, my question is how to deploy this micro service - (.war) file into the existing liferay tomcat server in order to use the url of the micro service in the existing legacy classes to retrieve some data from DB.

Please suggest me on this, Any kind of help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Sandy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploy .war file on a server (Liferay+Tomcat Bundle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296973/deploy-war-file-on-a-server-liferaytomcat-bundle)

Comment: @user3486184 That post says he have a liferay war file but my micro service has been developed in a normal eclipse IDE and want to deploy the war in existing liferay tomcat server.
Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Deploy Our WebApp into Liferay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134079/how-deploy-our-webapp-into-liferay). Just give it a go and deploy your war to the Tomcat. If you have a probiem with that, you should be more specific.

Comment: I checked the above possible duplicates which explain the same (.war deploy in tomcat). I have few version compatibility issues when deploying the .war in tomcat V6. But the solution might be the same as explained.

If its a liferay plugin based .war - you can auto deploy it or else you can drop it in the webapps folder of the tomcat server.